# zlib/libxml2 duplicate package?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum

I've been updating my amazon ec2 micro instance every month till now.
when i try to "yum update" i receive this error :

zlib-1.2.5-7.11.amzn1.x86_64 has installed conflicts libxml2 < ('0', '2.7.7', None): libxml2-**2.7.6**-4.12.amzn1.x86_64

zlib-1.2.5-7.11.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with zlib-1.2.3-27.9.amzn1.x86_64

yum update output: http://pastebin.com/Dfq0yphN

---

I've tried to update separately zlib and libxml2

- zlib: same "duplicate" error.
- libxml2: Transaction Check Error:  package libxml2-**2.7.8**-10.24.amzn1.x86_64 is already installed

what can i do?

Comment: I wouldn't use "Amazon Linux." From everything I've seen it's incredibly buggy, and this sort of thing happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by yum erase'ing all duplicate/obsolete packages.